# Save data from API to csv in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need help with saving data I read with API key to csv. The code I have is below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
def get_precip(gooddate):
    urlstart = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/API_KEY/history_'
    urlend = '/q/Switzerland/Zurich.json'
    url = urlstart + str(gooddate) + urlend
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    for summary in data['history']['dailysummary']:
        abc = ','.join((gooddate,summary['date']['year'],summary['date']['mon'],summary['date']['mday'],summary['precipm'], summary['maxtempm'], summary['meantempm'],summary['mintempm']))
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=abc)
        df.to_csv('/home/user/Desktop/2013_weather.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from datetime import date
    from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY

    a = date(2013, 1, 1)
    b = date(2013, 12, 31)

    for dt in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=a, until=b):
        get_precip(dt.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

I'm sure that can't work this way, because it need to be saved into some list or dictionary before transform into dataframe, but not sure how to do that this time. If save it to the list it will give me just one row? 
Any help is welcomed.
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) function of pandas. It also accepts urls as input as stated in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can return tuples from `get_precip`, append them to `list` and use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
def get_precip(gooddate):
    urlstart = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/API_KEY/history_'
    urlend = '/q/Switzerland/Zurich.json'
    url = urlstart + str(gooddate) + urlend
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    for summary in data['history']['dailysummary']:
        return (gooddate,summary['date']['year'],summary['date']['mon'],summary['date']['mday'],summary['precipm'], summary['maxtempm'], summary['meantempm'],summary['mintempm'])
```

---

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from datetime import date
    from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY

    a = date(2013, 1, 1)
    b = date(2013, 12, 31)

    L = []
    for dt in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=a, until=b):
        tup = get_precip(dt.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
        L.append(tup)
```

what is same as:

```
    L = [get_precip(dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")) for dt in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=a, until=b)]
```

---

```
    cols = ['date','date.year','date.mon','date.mday','precipm','maxtempm', 
            'meantempm','mintempm']     
    df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=cols)
    print (df.head())

           date date.year date.mon date.mday precipm maxtempm meantempm mintempm
    0  20130101      2013       01        01     0.0        7         2       -2
    1  20130102      2013       01        02     0.0        5         2       -3
    2  20130103      2013       01        03     0.0        4         0       -3
    3  20130104      2013       01        04     0.0        7         5        3

   df.to_csv('/home/user/Desktop/2013_weather.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks man, I think it's pratty much good, but I got an error : 
  File "weather_req.py", line 35, in get_precip
    for summary in data['history']['dailysummary']:
KeyError: 'history' . Do you know what that could be?

Comment: Do you change `API_KEY` ?

Comment: Hmmm, I think there should be reason API is not filtered only for some count of rows? I test it only with first 10, `b = date(2013, 1, 10)` and it working perfectly.

Comment: I think I find the problem. Zurich is provided, but some other cities that I need (Zurich was example) are not. Belgrade, Serbia (on this website is still Yugoslavia) is not, it doesn't have a history. Can you please try with Yugoslavia/Belgrade to be sure?

Comment: Unfortunately now I am on phone only. So tomorow it will be possible only.

Comment: That would be ok if you remember. Thank you. :)

Comment: I test it now with `urlend = '/q/Yugoslavia/Belgrade.json'` and it failed. But if use `urlend = '/q/Serbia/Belgrade.json'` it working nice.